# Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_multisite()

Tags: errors

My theme has a "function_exists" wrapper around the is_multisite() call as seen below...

```
if(function_exists(is_multisite()))
{
    //do something
}
```

However, I'm still getting this error on theme install...

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_multisite()
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the quotes: `if(function_exists('is_multisite'))`